# How can i find sharepoint 2010 Content Type xsd file?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i need to look xsd file for generate code so i need this document but i cant find these xsd files.
Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m not sure but let me try, if you are looking for the field feature it is placed @ 14 hive in the sub folder path \TEMPLATE\FEATURES\fields
And if you want content type feature definition its placed under \TEMPLATE\FEATURES\ctypes

Comment: look for the wss xsd file @ \TEMPLATE\XML